# Difference between addExtension and addDevToolsExtension

Tags: javascript, electron

Electron API exposes [`BrowserWindow.addExtension`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#browserwindowaddextensionpath) and [`BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#browserwindowadddevtoolsextensionpath) functions. Reading the source code I found out that [the former is called inside the latter](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/lib/browser/chrome-extension.js#L407), so it seems that both are somewhat equivalent in functionality.

The `BrowserWindow.addExtension` function has a confusing name because [the Electron team said regular chrome extensions won't be supported](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1498#issuecomment-96995155), however this function makes me think regular extensions *are* supported.

So...

1. What's the difference between these two?
2. Are regular chrome extensions supported in Electron or only dev tools ones?